# How to match keys from different objects to get value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, mongodb

I'm receiving the data via AJAX request. This data has a already defined key and value. After submitting the form and navigating to the next page it is getting saved into unique array, in MongoDB and has the same key and value.

I need to think of a logic that would match these two keys, so the selection is already pre-filled. So, if match is found, load value in `option` tags, if not, leave it empty.

Lets say my data where I'm getting the first AJAX response looks like this:

```
{
  data: [ 
          {
            id: "id1",
            something: "something1"
         },
           {
            id: "id1",
            something: "something2
         },
           .
           .
           .
      ]
}
```

When the user submits the form it generates a database entry, something like this:

```
object: [
            {
              id1: "id1"
            },
            .
            .
            .
  ]
```

So, how can I find matching and pre-fill the `<select><option></option></select>` tags.

The reason why I placed `...` is because it follows the same patter, there are no new data. It is one very long database.

Please help, I've breaking my head for 10 days over this and SO seems like a last resort.

Comment: could you please show some more data? without any `...`

Comment: The reason why I placed `...` is because it follows the same pattern. Nothing now. Does that help?

Comment: you want to filter `data` to only include the values with `ids` corresponding to the ones in `object` array is that what you're saying?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you want. What is `object` is it just some meta information about the contents, is everything inside the `[]` suppose to represent rows in a table? Usually you give the `<option>` a value attribute `<option value="id1">` this means that you can look at the data from the database then apply a `selected` attribute next to the corresponding `<option>`, does that answer your question?

Comment: @Dennis yes. I'm trying to get the values "id1" of the key (id) only if the match the already defined ones. It means, when a user selects an option and goes to the next page, the values are being saved in the db, as (key: value) reference. I need to find the way that will match the keys being saved to the one loaded from the db before, so the key can be automatically loaded into the <option> tags.

Comment: @CallumLinington - exactly! How do I achieve that?

Comment: Its easy, give me a minute

Comment: Seems pretty tricky to me mate.. :)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for https://plnkr.co/edit/Tc0n11zbRRxxDxSqkjoC?p=preview

Comment: Do be honest with you, I'm not sure... Could you please post it as an answer and make the real ajax request? Looks promising so far, tbh. :) Thanks.

Comment: No I can't put a real ajax request in because I don't have an endpoint to hit, if you don't know how to make ajax requests then look it up, either using `$.ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest`. They can easily replace the `setTimeout`. Lastly, if you aren't sure that is what you're looking for, it feels to me like you don't really know what you're asking, in which case you need to do a little bit more research

Comment: Nope, this was it. I know exactly what I was asking. Please post it as an answer and I will accept.Thanks.